# Implement Spring Actuator in my Spring MVC app without adding Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

Currently I have a legacy project that uses spring MVC. Now there is need to implement Spring boot actuator. So my questions are

1. Can I implement Spring Actuator in my Spring MVC app without adding
   Spring boot
2. Can I have both Spring boot and spring MVC in one single
   application. If Yes then how.

It would be great if someone can describe step by step implementation of it.
I am using Eclipse, Gradle, Tomcat

Answer (score 3):

**To answer your first question:**

1. yes You can use actuator in your spring mvc project. Add this to pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
       <version>Compatible version with mvc</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add configuration below

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @Import({EndpointAutoConfiguration.class , PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class , HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class
   })
   public class MyActuatorConfig {

       @Bean
       @Autowired
       public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
         return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
       }

      @Bean
      @Autowired
      public EndpointMvcAdapter metricsEndPoint(MetricsEndpoint delegate) {
         return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
     }
   }
   ```

**2. Answer your second questions**

Of course you can use  `Spring boot` and `spring MVC`, just simple have below as parent to manage all dependencies version etc..

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

and `spring-boot-starter-web` as dependency.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: For the first answer step 2 -
 Can you mention here the entry in spring servlet. i.e what values to be passed to make autowire work properly

Comment: after configuration /actuator end point should be available and same for metrics /metrics

Comment: But how to configure? i.e. I do not understand the step 2. Can you describe it in detail
Because since it has  @Autowired annotations where should we inject those dependency and how?
I am stuck at that point.
Thanks in advance

Comment: After creating this configuration class, you will have access of actuator end point which you can call by their end points to get info about metrics, etc, if you want to customize info default end pint returns then please have a look actuator documentation like if EndpointHandlerMapping is available as bean. This is sufficient to configure actuator.

Comment: Classes EndpointAutoConfiguration, PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration, HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration are not getting resolved with only spring-boot-actuator dependecy. 
I think it requires spring boot for that

Comment: It worked for step 1 with this adjusments: I used version 1.2.3.RELEASE for spring-boot-actuator for a 4.3.12.RELEASE spring-webmvc, and I changed the class of ActuatorConfig for Import({EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class
}) and add this Bean
    Autowired
    public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
        return new HealthMvcEndpoint(delegate);
    }