# Why other ends point not exposing except info and health in spring boot actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring-mvc application where I am trying to add spring boot actuator for performance metrics and other endpoints. I am not getting metrics, beans endpoint other than info and health endpoint. Can anyone please help me where I'm missed the configuration to get those endpoint?
Spring version : 5.2.8.RELEASE Spring Boot actuator version : 2.4.2
Below is my code :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Import({
    ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
    InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    InfoContributorAutoConfiguration.class,
    LogFileWebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    LoggersEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    BeansEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    MetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
    MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
    ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
    ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
    })
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(CorsEndpointProperties.class)
    public class ActuatorConfiguration2 {
    
    @Bean //taken from WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
       ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier 
            controllerEndpointsSupplier, EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties 
        corsProperties, WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties,Environment environment) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        //EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath());
        
        String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath(); 
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath); 
        boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = StringUtils.hasText(basePath) || 
        ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT);
     
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(),
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()), 
        shouldRegisterLinksMapping);
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath(){
        
            return () -> "/";
        }
   }
```

Default actuator endpoint url and response :

```
http://localhost:8090/com.springmvc.actuator.demo3/actuator/

{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/com.springmvc.actuator.demo3/actuator","templated":false},"health":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/com.springmvc.actuator.demo3/actuator/health","templated":false},"health-path":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/com.springmvc.actuator.demo3/actuator/health/{*path}","templated":true},"info":{"href":"http://localhost:8090/com.springmvc.actuator.demo3/actuator/info","templated":false}}}
```

what should i do for getting the other endpoints like : metrics, beans, caches etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info,health` are the default endpoints for spring boot actuator.

[Exposing endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints)

[image]

It seems that you did not declare endpoints on your `application.properties`. If so, pls try again by adding following:

```
// Enable everything with wildcard
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

// You can also disable some of them
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=jolokia,liquibase
```

Comment: Thank you. I added properties file as per your suggestion but metrics end point is not coming. I added below EndPointConfiguration class for metrics

WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class

For Metrics which configuration file I need to add?

Comment: Ohhh, it seems that your project is not a spring boot application. Is it true ?

Comment: Yes, It's not a spring boot project. It's a spring-mvc project where i'm trying to add spring boot actuator.

Comment: You may want to take a look to the following steps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009502/implement-spring-actuator-in-my-spring-mvc-app-without-adding-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009502/implement-spring-actuator-in-my-spring-mvc-app-without-adding-spring-boot). **Especially, configuration class...**

Comment: I gone through above link, but that example will work old-version(1.X) . package and class structure were completely changed in latest version(2.x)

Comment: Except metrics others endpoint are  working fine.

Comment: Followed below link and my application is working as expected.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031056/problem-with-spring-actuator-metrics-without-enableautoconfiguration